# Trouble Running Emacs Daemon on Ubuntu Boot

Tags: init.d, emacs

I want to run [emacs as a daemon](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon), on [Ubuntu bootup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).

The daemon call works, and the init script works, when called in a logged in session. However, when I boot my system, the emacs init script doesn't seem to have been run.

- ***i)*** I can't call `emacsc`, and
- ***ii)*** there's no evidence in `/var/logs/boot*`.
- ***iii)*** in my shell, if I run `emacs --daemon`, I can then use the emacs client

Is there any special wand-waving to be done? Or any better way to trouble-shoot this issue?

Comment: What is your init script called and is it in the correct runlevel? To be sure if it starts include something like `date > /tmp/test` in it and after booting check if it's there.

Comment: Nice trick - thank-you. I was trying to think of a way of verifying that an init script was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page in the Emacs wiki recommends running Emacs as user from an init script. This is not what init scripts were designed for, so I'm not surprised that it could cause issues.

Forget that and start the Emacs daemon from your `.profile` or from your crontab. Most modern cron implementations (and in particular Ubuntu's) allow the syntax

```
@crontab emacs --daemon
```

Or you could start Emacs on first use, by invoking

```
emacsclient -a ''
```

The service management framework isn't useful to manage Emacs.

Comment: I used ***.bash_profile***, but essentially the same thing. Cheers.

Comment: @Gilles - 4 years later: would you still recommend the above method? For example, compared to the docs, which have way more config: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon

Comment: @n1k31t4 These days you might use systemd to start the daemon, if you're running a not-too-old Linux. But definitely don't start Emacs from an init script. Init scripts are system-wide. Do it from the _user_ systemd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the accepted answer dealing with crontab doesn't work with the current version on Ubuntu 18. This is the correct incantation for crontab:

`@reboot emacs --daemon`